# Improved current mirrors

Tags: current-mirror

I do not understand "The circuit on the right is a feedback amplifier with loop gain T. Since all time constants in that loop are of the same order of magnitude, they create a system with several poles"

How do I derive the feedback loop gain T = (gm1)*(Rin) ?

Could anyone point me to some maths reference / equations ? Razavi book does not mention about the circuit on the right though.

[image]

Note: the current mirror on the right is a 4T Wilson current mirror https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilson_current_mirror#A_Four-Transistor_Improved_Mirror

Let me start with 3T Wilson mirror in BJT implementation.

[image]

> A feedback path is thus formed that regulates IC3 so that it is nearly
>   equal to the input current, reducing the systematic gain error caused
>   by finite βF.

**systematic gain error due to finite βF ?**

Answer (score 1):

Yeap----those topologies tend to oscillate. Various bipolar opamps in the semiconductor industry had those problems, from what I was taught in OpAmp design class.

Comment: From https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barkhausen_stability_criterion, how do I prevent oscillation other than keeping the loop gain less than unity ?

I understand that M1 provide 180 degree phase shift and M4 provides zero degree phase shift.

Comment: You need a good high frequency model of the transistor; that includes the resistive paths from terminals (E B C) into the active region, thus the R+C phase shifts are (crudely) described; the real elements are usually "distributed" and messy. The specific silicon layout sets the parasitics; some bipolars have 2 or 4 or more base contacts, perhaps on both sides of the emitter. FETS with stripes can be better modeled, with that awareness. The substrate/well ties provide delays for charge collections and that modeling is your task.

Comment: I am reading "Ultra High-Compliance CMOS Current Mirrors for
Low Voltage Charge Pumps and References" from Charlon.  It is quite good.